# Computing $(A\otimes I + I \otimes A)^{-1} \text{vec}B$

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, matrix-equations, control-theory, kronecker-product

Suppose I have two positive semi-definite $n$-by-$n$ matrices $A$, $B$ and an $n$-by-$n$ identity matrix $I$, and I'm looking for a way to compute, approximate or bound the following quantity:

$$(A\otimes I + I \otimes A)^{-1} \text{vec}B$$

Concretely I'm dealing with matrices with $n$ ranging from $100$ to $4000$, so $A$ is easy to invert, while $A \otimes I$ is too large, so need a way to compute this using operations on $n$-by-$n$ matrices

Additionally, I found the following to give a decent approximation when $A$, $B$ can be Kronecker-factored, wondering if there's a reason for that.

$$0.5 A^{-0.5} B  A^{-0.5}$$

Any tips or literature pointers are appreciated!

Comment: Is your issue connected to the vector space of matrices commuting with the given matrix $A$ like in https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2009/650970/ ?

Comment: You might want to try using the [integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation) for the solution, with some kind of quadrature method.

Comment: The integral formula mentionned by @Omnomnomnom might be a way to reach your approximation $0.5 A^{-0.5} B  A^{-0.5}$.

Comment: Why don't you answer my little question asked 2 days ago ?

Comment: The motivation was to compute Equation 3 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.03774.pdf , I don't know if matrices commuting helps here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation is equivalent to solving the following equation for $P$

$$
A\,P + P\,A^\top = B. \tag{1}
$$

Such equation also solves for the [infinite time (controllability) Gramian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability_Gramian#Controllability_Gramian), which can also be calculated with

$$
P = -\int_0^\infty e^{A\,t}\,B\,e^{A^\top t}\,dt. \tag{2}
$$

This integral should also be of size $n \times n$. As time goes to infinity $e^{A\,t}$ is not well defined when $A$ is positive semi-definite. It can also be [noted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) that in order to be able to solve for $P$ the spectra of $A$ and $-A$ need to be disjoint. In order words $A$ can't have an eigenvalue of zero, which would imply that $A$ should be positive definite instead of positive semi-definite. When multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by minus ones keeps it equivalent to the original problem. This is also equivalent to multiplying both $A$ and $B$ by minus one, which transforms $(2)$ into

$$
P = \int_0^\infty e^{-A\,t}\,B\,e^{-A^\top t}\,dt. \tag{3}
$$

Now the term $e^{-A\,t}$ does stay bounded and converges to zero as time goes to infinity. The rate of how fast this integral converges should be roughly inversely proportional to the smallest eigenvalue of $A$, however any finite time numerical approximation of this integral can be used as a lower bound for $P$.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it's implemented in scipy already as https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_sylvester.html

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo you can just multiply both $A$ and $B$ with minus one in the first equation, which results in the following integral$$P = -\int_0^\infty e^{-A\,t}\,B\,e^{-A^\top t}\,dt.$$

Comment: Kwin, the equation is $AP+PA^T=B$ and in the formula for $P$: i)  if the condition  on $A$ is that its eigenvalues have $>0$ real part, then change $A,A^T$ into $-A,-A^T$. ii)   if the condition  on $A$ is that its eigenvalues have $<0$ real part, then change $B$ into $-B$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I have updated my answer.

Comment: @loupblanc I indeed mixed up a minus a sign in $(1)$ (and the equation after that), it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vcc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial} \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$The SANE algorithm by Raydan & Martinez is basically Barzilai-Borwein applied to a system of nonlinear equations
rather than a *scalar* cost function. It satisfies a least-squares form of the Secant Equation, so it can also be viewed as a Quasi-Newton method.

Anyway, their algorithm can be easily adapted to matrix-valued functions
$$\eqalign{
F(X) &\equiv AX+XA^T-B = 0 \qquad&\{ {\rm matrix\;NLE\;function} \} \\
\\
X_0 &= I &\{ {\rm initialize} \} \\
F_0 &= F(X_0) \\
\\
k &= 1  &\{ {\rm first\;step} \} \\
dX_1 &= -F_0\cdot 10^{-5} \\
X_1 &= X_0 + dX_1 \\
F_1 &= F(X_1) \\
dF_1 &= F_1 - F_0 \\
\\
{\rm while\;} \big\|F_k\big\|_F^2 \:&> 10^{-12} \\
dX_{k+1} &= -\fracLR{dX_k:dF_k}{dF_k:dF_k}F_k
 \qquad&\{ {\rm Barzilia\,Borwein\;step} \} \\
X_{k+1} &= X_k + dX_{k+1} \\
dF_{k+1} &= A\:dX_{k+1} + dX_{k+1}\,A^T 
 &\equiv\; F_{k+1} - F_k \\
F_{k+1} &= F_k + dF_{k+1} \\
k &= k+1 \\
}$$
where a colon has been used to denote the matrix inner product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
The nice thing about this algorithm is that it deals with
$n\times n$ matrices rather than $n^2\times n^2$ Kronecker matrices.
Furthermore, it does not require any matrix inversions or the evaluation of transcendental matrix functions. Each iteration requires exactly **one** evaluation of the objective function. All of these features make each iteration relatively quick.

Answer (score 1):

Given symmetric matrices $\mathrm A \succ \mathrm O_n$ and $\mathrm B \succeq \mathrm O_n$, let

$$\mathrm X (t) := \int_0^t e^{-\tau \mathrm A} \mathrm B e^{-\tau \mathrm A} \,\mathrm d \tau$$

Using integration by parts,

$$\mathrm A \mathrm X (t) = \cdots = -\dot{\mathrm X} (t) + \mathrm B - \mathrm X (t) \mathrm A$$

and, thus, we obtain the following matrix differential equation

$$\boxed{\dot{\mathrm X} = - \mathrm A \mathrm X - \mathrm X \mathrm A + \mathrm B}$$

with initial condition $\mathrm X (0) = \mathrm O_n$. Assuming $\rm X$ converges to a steady-state, $\dot{\mathrm X} = \mathrm O_n$, we obtain the following linear matrix equation

$$\mathrm A \mathrm X + \mathrm X \mathrm A = \mathrm B$$

whose solution we denote by $\bar{\rm X}$. This is the *desired* solution.

Using a *numerical* ODE solver, we then integrate the matrix differential equation above and find an *approximate* value of matrix $\bar{\rm X}$. Since matrix $\rm X (t)$ is symmetric for all $t \geq 0$, we can [half-vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Half-vectorization) both sides of the matrix differential equation in order to obtain a $\binom{n+1}{2}$-dimensional state vector (rather than a $n^2$-dimensional state vector, which would be wasteful).

---

#### Appendix

Note that the solution of the matrix differential equation is given by

$$\mathrm X (t) = \bar{\mathrm X} - e^{-t \mathrm A} \bar{\mathrm X} e^{-t \mathrm A}$$

Since $\mathrm A \succ \mathrm O_n$,

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \mathrm X (t) = \bar{\mathrm X}$$

If matrix $\rm A$ were allowed to have an eigenvalue at zero, it would be unpleasant.