# Controllability Gramian via integration by parts

Tags: integration, matrices, matrix-equations, closed-form, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to program something like [this article](http://arl.cs.utah.edu/pubs/ICRA2013-1.pdf). On page 3, there's the following equation (eq. 6) that should be expressible in closed-form:

$$\int_0^te^{(A(t-t'))} M e^{(A^T(t-t'))}dt'$$

where $A$ is a nilpotent matrix. Both $A$ and $M$ are constant matrices and,  for this specific case, of size $5 \times 5$. I've tried integrating by parts, but after substituting $x = t - t'$ and simplifying, I was basically right back at the start:

$$A \left( \int_0^te^{(Ax)} M e^{(A^Tx)}dx \right) + \left( \int_0^te^{(Ax)} M e^{(A^Tx)}dx \right) A^T = e^{(Ax)} M e^{(A^Tx)} - M$$

which is basically just applying

$$\int u'v + \int uv' = [uv]$$

How should I tackle this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google "controllability Gramian". Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3332306/339790).

Comment: Found the answer?