# bounding norm of $X$ in $AX+XA=2B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that norm of $X$ is bounded by largest eigenvalue of $BA^{-1}$ for positive definite matrices $A$,$B$?
$$AX+XA=2B$$

If $A$ and $B$ have a common basis of eigenvectors, then the quantities are equal, using approach of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3355045/998). Empirically, norm(X) seems to be smaller in other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the norm in question is the induced $2$-norm. Note that $X$ must be Hermitian. Let $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ be the largest-sized eigenvalue of $X$, $v$ be a corresponding eigenvector and $u=A^{1/2}v$. Then
$$
2\lambda\|u\|^2=2\lambda v^\ast Av=v^\ast(AX+XA)v=2v^\ast Bv=2u^\ast A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}u.
$$
Therefore
$$
\|X\|=|\lambda|=\frac{u^\ast A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}u}{\|u\|^2}\le\rho(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})=\rho(BA^{-1}).
$$