# Least squares solution to underdetermined Lyapunov equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I need to solve an underdetermined Lyapunov equation for unknown $n\times n$ matrix $X$.

$$AX + XA = B$$

The naive method is to vectorize $x=\operatorname{vec}(X)$ and use a least squares solver on the following equation to find the least-squares solution.

$$(I\otimes A + A\otimes I)x = \operatorname{vec}B$$

Experimentally I [found](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/lyapunov.nb) that when $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite, I get the same solution by expressing $X$ in terms of $U,s$, the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A$ as below ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3355045/998)) and modifying pointwise (Hadamard) division to [skip](https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/1a258310b266ac7ade35b025c9e6fae3#file-solve_lyapunov-py-L13) division by zero, like how pseudo-inverse implementations do it.

$$X=U \left( \frac{U' BU}{s + s'} \right) U'$$

Does this appear in the literature, or does someone see a way to prove that this recovers least-squares solution?

**Example**

$$\text{A=}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 8 & -8 & -8 \\
 -8 & 9 & 8 \\
 -8 & 8 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\text{B=}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 5 & 5 & -5 \\
 5 & 9 & -3 \\
 -5 & -3 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This equation is underdetermined because $A$ and $B$ are singular, hence standard Lyapunov solver fails. However, both least squares and truncated spectral decomposition methods succeed with the same answer:

$$X=\frac{1}{640}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1789 & 2928 & -1329 \\
 2928 & 4672 & -1968 \\
 -1329 & -1968 & 869 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-lyapunov-undetermined.nb)

Comment: Since $U\ {\rm and}\ s$ both depend on $X$, the new equation is implicit. How do you calculate the RHS, i.e. eigenvectors/eigenvalues of an unknown matrix?

Comment: They depend on A not X, heres constructive proof this works https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3355045/998

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be frank, this is obvious. Let $USU^\ast$ be a unitary diagonalisation of $A$ and write $S=\operatorname{diag}(s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n)$. Let $C=U^\ast BU$ and $Y=U^\ast XU$. Then
$$
\|AX+XA-B\|_F^2
=\|SY+YS-C\|_F^2
=\sum_{i,j}|(s_i+s_j)y_{ij}-c_{ij}\big|^2.\tag{1}
$$
As each $|(s_i+s_j)y_{ij}-c_{ij}\big|$ contains a unique element of $Y$, minimising the above is equivalent to minimising each residual individually. When $s_i+s_j>0$, the minimum value of $|(s_i+s_j)y_{ij}-c_{ij}\big|$ is zero and it is attained by $y_{ij}=(s_i+s_j)^{-1}c_{ij}$. When $s_i+s_j=0$, the residual is equal to the constant $|c_{ij}|$. Hence $y_{ij}$ can assume any value and the *least-norm* least-squares solution is $y_{ij}=0$. So, in summary, the least-norm solution to the least-squares problem can be written as
$$
y_{ij}
=\begin{cases}
\frac{c_{ij}}{s_i+s_j}&\text{if } s_i+s_j\ne0,\\
0&\text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$
i.e., $y_{ij}=(s_i+s_j)^+c_{ij}$ where $(s_i+s_j)^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of the number $s_i+s_j$. Since $\|Y\|_F=\|UYU^\ast\|_F$, the matrix $X=UYU^\ast$ constructed from $Y$ is also the least-norm solution to the least-squares problem of minimising $(1)$.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Write the Lyapunov/Sylvester equation as
$$\eqalign{
F(X) = \LR{AX + XA - B} \;\approx\; 0 \\
}$$
The associated Least-Squares problem is
$$\eqalign{
\min_X\:\tfrac12\,\frob{F}^2 \\
}$$
Calculate the differential and gradient of the LS function
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \tfrac12\,\LR{F:F}\\
d\phi &= F:dF \\
 &= F:\LR{A\:dX+dX\:A} \\
 &= \LR{AF+FA}:dX \\
\grad{\phi}{X}
 &= AF+FA \\
 &= A^2X + 2AXA + XA^2 - AB - BA \\
}$$
To solve the zero-gradient condition, use the technique from your previous posts and substitute the eigenvalue decomposition
$$\eqalign{
A &= USU^T, \qquad s=\diag S,\quad S=\Diag s \\
}$$
and use this to define some new matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
C &= U^TBU, \qquad
Y &= U^TXU, \qquad
P &= S^2 = \Diag p \\
}$$
Pre/post multiplying the zero-gradient condition by $U^T\ {\rm and}\ U\:$ yields
$$\eqalign{
\LR{PY + 2SYS + YP} &= \LR{SC+CS} \\
}$$
Now employ standard tricks involving Hadamard products, diagonal matrices, and the all-ones vector $\o$
$$\eqalign{
SMP = sp^T\odot M \\
SM = s\o^T\odot M \\
MS = \o s^T\odot M \\
}$$
to rewrite the condition as
$$\eqalign{
&Y\odot\LR{p\o^T+ 2ss^T +\o p^T} = C\odot\LR{s\o^T+\o s^T} \\
&Y = C\odot\LR{s\o^T+\o s^T}\oslash\LR{p\o^T+ 2ss^T +\o p^T} \\
&Y = C\oslash\LR{s\o^T+\o s^T} \\
}$$
So the least-squares solution to the problem is indeed
$$\eqalign{
X &= UYU^T \\\\
}$$

---

In the above, $\{\oslash,\,\odot\}$ denote Hadamard division and multiplication, while a colon is used to denote the matrix inner product (aka the Frobenius product)
$$A:B = \trace{A^TB} $$